Can't access iframe of the same domain
I'm trying to load a pdf in an iframe and set the height to match the document's height.
var frame = document.getElementById("preview_frame");
frame.onload = function() {
  this.style.height = this.contentWindow.document.documentElement.scrollHeight + 'px';
}
frame.src = frame.getAttribute("data-url") + "/files/preview/" + target;

The document is getting loaded but I'm seeing this error in the console:

Uncaught DOMException: Permission denied to access property "document" on cross-origin object

Both the page with the iframe and the pdf document are hosted locally within the same domain:
page url: https://locdev/project-url/public_html
pdf url: https://locdev/project-url/public_html/files/preview/file.pdf
I even tried adding
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://locdev"

To
/project-url/public_html/files/preview/.htaccess

And I see it is being added when I open the pdf document directly, but I'm still getting the error on the page with the iframe.
I am noticing that if I replace the pdf file with an image for example, then the code works.
How can I solve this problem?

There must be something you're not telling us; please add a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. But CORS is irrelevant to your issue.

The issue is that a PDF is not web content.
To overcome this you need to use a JavaScript PDF render, such as PDF.js. You can then combine this with iframe-resizer to make the iframe resize to the size of the document.

A bit confusing, how is a pdf not web content, but a jpg is, when both viewed at an url which starts with http?
